# Navigating a many-to-many Tables relationship in a Dataset (Optimization)

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset

I have a Dataset that contains tables from a university database,
two(actually more) of these tables contain a many to many relationship,
specifically I have a,

**Students** table (Contains information about students)
**Courses** table (Contains information about the courses)
**TakesCourses** table (Which is an intermediary table between the **Students** and **Courses** tables, every student can have many courses)

I want to input a "student ID" and fetch all the records from the **Courses** table according to the records found in **TakesCourses** table.

My code ***WORKS*** and it is as follows:

```
string stdInfo = string.Empty;

DataRow[] drStudent = null;
DataRow drCourses = null;
DataRow[] drStdCrs = null;

drStudent = universityDS.Tables["Students"]
    .Select(string.Format("StudentID='{0}'", txtStudentID.Text));

stdInfo += string.Format("Student {0} {1}:\nTaking Courses:",
    drStudent[0]["FirstName"].ToString().Trim(),
    drStudent[0]["LastName"].ToString().Trim());

drStdCrs = drStudent[0].GetChildRows(
    universityDS.Relations["FK_TakesCourses_Students"]);

//Can I optimize here? Is there a better way to code this
if (drStdCrs.Length > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < drStdCrs.Length; i++)
    {
        drCourses = drStdCrs[i].GetParentRow(
            universityDS.Relations["FK_TakesCourses_Courses"]);

        stdInfo += string.Format("\nCourse: {0}",
            drCourses["CourseName"]);
    }               
}

MessageBox.Show(stdInfo);
```

My question is, how can I optimize the code after the comments?
is there a better way to write this?

(Note: I am a recovering developer, trying to refresh my skills)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with JDoig. Here is an example of how your code might look like while using LINQ to SQL:

```
string stdInfo = string.Empty;
string studentId = txtStudentID.Text;

using (var db = new CourseDataContext())
{
    Student student = (
        from student in db.Students
        where student.StudentID == studentId
        select student).Single();

    stdInfo += string.Format("Student {0} {1}:\nTaking Courses:",
        student.FirstName, student.LastName);

    var courseNames =
        from taken in student.TakesCourses
        select taken.Course.CourseName;

    foreach (string courseName in courseNames)
    {
        stdInfo += string.Format("\nCourse: {0}", courseNames);
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(stdInfo);
```

As you will see it takes far less code and does a much better job in showing the intent of the code.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, as I said I'll be working on Linq API as of tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

If the version of the .NET framework you are using (or able to use based on the project) supports LINQ2SQL I **HIGHLY** recommend you take the time to learn LINQ as it will make your life a thousand times easier both when dealing with SQL and in every day coding with .NET.

In this day and age I would avoid in-line SQL unless it is your only resort, as it's often punishable by death in most establishments :¬(.

Comment: "n this day and age I would avoid in-line SQL unless it is your only resort, as it's often punishable by death in most establishments :¬(."

That's an undelightful morbid vision! :D

Actually I was planing on getting into LINQ API first thing tomorrow, since I am learning the 3.5 .Net framework.
Thanks for the feedback, appreciate it.